# Does c++23 break unmove

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++23

The wording in the standard regarding implicit move changed in c++23
see https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2266r3.html
relevant part is:

> a returned move-eligible id-expression is always an xvalue

this seems to break the popular but unwise 'unmove'

```
template<typename T>
auto unmove(T&& v) -> std::remove_reference_t<T>& { return v; }
```

Current implementations seem to agree: https://godbolt.org/z/3n39rGM7b

**Is this breaking change intended, or can we expect a DR?**

Comment: I haven't see `unmove` being used even once. And the fix is simple: `std::remove_reference_t<T>& vv = v; return vv;`, so I'm not sure if it's worth the effort to fix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since this breakage is mentioned in the [Implementation experience](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2266r3.html#experience) section of P2266R3, I'd say it's quite obviously intentional.

The fix is simple: just add an explicit cast.

```
template<typename T>
auto unmove(T&& v) -> std::remove_reference_t<T>& {
    return static_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>&>(v);
}
```

Comment: `remove_reference_t<T>&` is a very long way to spell `T&` :-)